All sound has stopped after last kernel upgrade!! Been fine until today
Ubuntu 24.04 studio clean install a month ago.
On A trigkey S7 mini PC, all fine until today.
All fine until today. Fired up chrome and no sound.
All sound apps show my scarlet i212 as working chrome says sound is outputting.
Reboot and sound starts for a minute then stops.
I have tried alsamixer and alsa. Pipe Wire is connected to correct output.
This is a studio OS and my studio is silent.
I'm at a loss, nothing seems to work. I've tried rebooting, tried logging out.
I have the latest Kernel it seems.
Any ideas please.
